# Is it offensive to mimic Japanese style typography?

Tags: typography, japanese

I'm preparing a proposal for a Japanese company and have been asked to create a sign. I've been asked (by an American) to use a Japan-esque type of some sort on the signage. I would like to respect cultural sensitivity by making sure we're not going to offend. Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend entirely on the viewer? Is "the American" your boss? Then do what he/she wants. If not, ignore it if it doesn't sit well with you.

Comment: If the text is in English, I would avoid the use of "wonton fonts."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so at all. Japanese "style" is just calligraphy done with a brush and ink stick. To say it is offensive would be like saying block print is offensive. Don't think of it as Japanese, think of it as calligraphy.